# How to restrict user from navigating on click of tabs of navbar in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular10

I have a navbar which I want to navigate through only next and back buttons, clicking directly on tabs must be restricted. Below is my code which I tried but they are not working as expected,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link mr-5" [ngClass]="href == '/expert-welcome/expert-profile'? '': 'disabled'" [routerLink]="['/expert-welcome/expert-profile']" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
                    <b class="circularBold">Profile Details</b>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link mr-5" [routerLink]="['/expert-welcome/expert-education']" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
                    <b class="circularBold">Education & Experience</b>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link mr-5">
                    <b class="circularBold">Services Offerings</b>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link mr-5">
                    <b class="circularBold">Availability & Fees</b>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">
                    <b class="circularBold">Listing Details</b>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

With this approach, it's working partially, when I navigate through back and next buttons, the route is loading but the value isn't getting patched, I'll have to reload the page for the new value to get patched.

In approach 2, I have removed routerLink and routerLinkActive, but I want to show a different css for an active tab as below.

[image]

Better solution or suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) for the same, so we can fork and do necessary changes.

Comment: If you are using routes in your navbar, lookup guards. Then you can determine with a service if the user is allowed to access a specific page, this will also protect against if someone will navigate via typing the restricted url. Official doc can be found here https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access

Answer (score 0):

```
<a routerLink="/your/path"><span (click)="preventRloute($event)">Test link</span></a>
```

and writ a function

```
function preventRloute($event: MouseEvent) {
if (condition) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    // your code...
    return;
}
// navigates
}
```